# How to fix DSL upstream SNR margin

Tags: networking, dsl

```
                   Downstream   Upstream     
SNR Margin:              20.2      4.9  dB
Line Attenuation:        34.5     34.1  dB
Data Rate:             4096      298    kbps
Max Rate:             14660      284    kbps
Power:                    0.0     12.2  dBm
CRC:                      0        2
```

Comment: Please give us more information. What are you talking about? What is the context? what is the situation? What is broken or not working? Use the EDIT button to add relevant information to the body of the question itself rather than commenting here.

Comment: Is vdsl available in your region?

Answer (score 1):

To improve the upstream SNR margin on a DSL line, you'd either have to get the modem to transmit using more power, your you'd need to reduce the noise on the line (possibly by fixing faulty or degraded wiring).

Unless your home's telephone wiring is faulty, there's not much you as a consumer can do to fix this. This is really a problem for a DSL technician or telephone company lineman.

Comment: Nice job cleaning this up. To add to this answer: It may help to go with a higher category cable when replacing faulty inside wiring. Going from cat-3 to cat-5e solid can make a huge difference (straight-shot going from the modem to the Demarcation point.) I shutter at the thought of how old someone's cat-3 phone-line could actually be in their house. +1